# проблема с получением данных с JSONserver(JS,fetch)

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Есть код который работает с JSON данными определенного сайта:
нашел на форуме пример: https://codepen.io/alcovegan/pen/YQRXGa?editors=1011#0

Но когда запускаю локальный сервер json (через команду json-server --watch db.json)
данный код работает с моими значениями,но выводит undefined вместо значения под индексом "two"( в консоли тишина),хотя по идее должен вывести слово "Angela",объясните пожалуйста что неправильно и что нужно исправить.

Код db.json

```
{
"people": [
{
"one": "John"
},

{
"two": "Angela"
},

{
"three": "Alex"
}

]
}
```

---

Код html+js

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="online"></div>
<script>
const online = document.getElementById('online');

setInterval(() => {
fetch(' http://localhost:3000/people')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => online.innerHTML = data.two)
}, 3000)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Насколько я вижу чтобы добраться до `Angela` надо сначала обратиться к `data.people`, и в этом массиве объектов уже искать.

Comment: В вашем файле db.json и в примере разные структуры json. Посмотрите на них внимательно и сравните

Comment: да..у данных json разная структура,так что я сделал вывод с помощью перебора массива.спасибо за ваши советы!